# Find a single convex closed curve of fixed length in the plane that has the smallest average distance to the origin

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, calculus-of-variations, plane-curves

(Reformulation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481103/minimum-average-distance-to-the-origin-for-convex-curves-in-the-plane))

I want to find which convex closed curve of length $2\pi$ has the smallest average distance of all its points to the origin. For instance, given a curve $\gamma(s)$ with arc-length parametrization, the average distance to the origin is given by:

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\gamma| \, ds$$

So I need to minimize that integral over all $\gamma(s)$ that satisfy the condition of being: closed, convex, and with length $2\pi$.

Here is my approach:

First I calculated that integral for the family of ovals with curvature $\kappa(s)=1 /\left(a^{2} \cos ^{2}(s)+a^{-2} \sin ^{2}(s)\right)$, for several $a$. For $a=1$, it's just the circle with average distance to the origin of 1. As $a$ increases, the curve gets flatter and the value for the average distance decreases to a value of $\pi/4$, when $a\to \infty$.

So $\pi/4$ is my best lower bound so far, I tried using Euler-Lagrange equation but I'm not sure how many constraints to use.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, I was suggested to be more precise with the question, so I added more information and re-formulated the idea. I'm deleting the previous one

Comment: OK but you must at least refer this first question in case there are comments or even new answers given to the previous answer...

Comment: The most obvious way to enforce convexity would be to work in terms of the [support function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function), which would allow you to represent $\gamma$ as a function $S^1 \to \mathbb R$ with the only remaining constraint being the perimeter/arclength. Not sure offhand if this can be expressed neatly in terms of the support function, though.